# Leaks with ARC enabled

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, free, memory-leaks, calloc

My code seems to be leaking when using C arrays and I'm not sure why.

```
/* LeakyClass.m */

@property (nonatomic, assign) char **array1;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id __strong *array2;
@property (nonatomic, assign) unsigned short currentDictCount;

//...

- (id)initWithCapacity:(unsigned short)capacity
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _array1 = (char **)calloc(sizeof(char*), capacity);  //Leak
        _array2 = (id __strong *)calloc(sizeof(id), capacity);  //Leak
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    free(_array1);
    free(_array2);
    _array1 = NULL;
    _array2 = NULL;
}

- (void)addObjectToArray2:(id)object andCharToArray1:(char *)str
{
    [self array2][[self currentDictCount]] = object;
    [self array1][[self currentDictCount]] = str;

    [self setCurrentDictCount:[self currentDictCount] + 1];
}

@end
```

I call `LeakyClass` with this:

```
/* OtherClass.m */

LeakyClass *leaky = [[LeakyClass alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
[leaky addObjectToArray2:object andCharToArray1:"1"];  // Leak
[leaky addObjectToArray2:@"example" andCharToArray1:"2"];  /Leak
[leaky addObjectToArray2:[NSURL URLWithString:exampleString] andCharToArray1:"3"];  /Leak
```

Instruments are pointing to each of the values passed onto the `LeakyClass` to add to array 1. In this example, `object`, `@"example"` and `[NSURL URLWithString:exampleString]`. Instruments is also pointing to the `calloc`s for `_array1` and `_array2` but I free both of them in `dealloc`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why aren't you using `NSMutableArrays`?

Comment: Not only that, but this looks like a rudimentary implementation of an `NSMutableDictionary`. Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: True, he could use objective-c classes, but I think that is a good practice for a beginner to try these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all using `__strong` with an `id` pointer is meaningless, ARC will try to send the `release`, `retain` etc messages to the pointer, not to each of you objects (given your current implementation it doesn't even know how many objects you dynamically allocated) , so, in short terms, you're the same with or without it. As for the leak, try to free your pointers before alloc.

Anyways, as others mentioned, why not use `NSArray` or/and `NSDictionary`?

**Edit** following the comments below:

When I said "you're the same with or without it" I meant, it will not help you in any way with your memory management, it's meaningless. However, you have to have an ownership qualifier, so just removing it will end up in an error (as you reported). You should use

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id __unsafe_unretained *array2;
```

As for your memory problem, did you tried to `free` before `alloc`? What happens if `initWithCapacity:` gets called twice, I know you won't call it twice, but there's no guarantee for instruments to know.

Also [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) are the specs for you to understand better ARC and all the qualifiers.

Comment: This is not exactly true. Removing `__strong`, in this case, will cause a compile error.

Comment: `Pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership.`

Comment: I see. I'm following you now. Yes, that fixed the problems. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

malloc/calloc memory is not ref counted, you strongly decide when to allocate it and when to deallocate it.Setting that pointer to NULL doesn't free it, use free:

```
free(_array1); 
free(_array2);
```

This is like a dealloc message, but handles raw memory, not objective-c classes.
If you want to include also raw memory in the garbage collector, wrap it using NSData:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSData* wrapper1;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSData* wrapper2;
```

Wrap the data:

```
wrapper1= [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy: _array1 length: capacity*sizeof(char*) freeWhenDone: YES];
wrapper2= [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy: _array2 length: capacity*sizeof(id) freeWhenDone: YES];
```

And don't free it, but instead set to nil wrapper1 and wrapper2.But even without overriding the dealloc method, you'll have all the memory freed after the object dies.

Comment: I'll try this just now. I am already freeing the arrays in dealloc but I will try with NSData and see if it stops the leak.

Comment: This code works perfectly and fixes the problem with the arrays leaking. Thanks! Do you have idea why the objects that are being passed for insertion into array2 (see bottom of question) are leaking?

Comment: Because _array2 has strong references, and implicitly retains all objects.